# Segmentation fault while using malloc and taking input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have something of this sort:

```
int n,m;
scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*n*m);
for(int i=0;i<m*n;scanf("%d",arr+i),i++);
```

Now for say n=2 and m = 3, It accepts the first five numbers, and gives a segmentation fault on the sixth number. I tried printing stuff immediately after the loop, but its not being printed, any idea what the problem could be? I've used similar constructs extensively and have never encountered a problem before.

EDIT 1:
The problem was later on in the program, but the thing is I had a printf immediately after the loop, and it didn't print anything, so I assumed that it had to be here. Why didn't the printf print anything? Does it have something to do with parallel execution? And sorry for the bad format, I'm new to stack overflow.

Comment: Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** `gdb` and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Next time you ask some question on SO, give some [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This *fix my code* question is off-topic. Read also [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), notably of `malloc` and `scanf`

Comment: "something of this sort".... Please study the concept of a [mcve].

Comment: Check in the debugger the values (with a breakpoint on the `for`  loop) of `m`, `n`, `arr`. I'm sure you'll be surprised.

Comment: This is by far the *worst* way of writing a loop I have seen.

Comment: Please stop writing 'clever' code.  It's confusing and difficult to debug.  Oh - and it often goes wrong:(   Developing software, which includes testing, debugging and maintenance, is difficult enough without over-complicating and almost-obfuscating the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
int n,m;
printf( "Enter two digits" );
int scanCount = scanf( "%d %d", &m, &n );
if( scanCount < 2 ){   
    perror("Input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   
}
scanCount = 0;
size_t size = sizeof( int ) * n * m;
int * arr = (int *) malloc( size );
if ( arr == NULL ) { 
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
};
for( int i = 0; i < m * n; i++ ){
    if ( scanf( "%d", arr + i ) )
        scanCount++;
}
if( scanCount < m*n ){   
    perror("Input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for( int i=0; i<n*m; i++ ){
    printf( "\nValue at %d : %d\n", i, *( arr + i ) );
}
```

I have modified the above given program a little bit, and now it works for me.
The **[malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc)** function expects "std::size_t size" ( we can also provide integer values ) as argument which is the size of the memory we need to allocate. Please visit http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc for any reference.

Also we should specify the type of the memory we are creating ( otherwise it may produce an error in some compilers, like this "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*'" ). In this case we are creting an array of integers and we can use type cating, for example 
(int *) malloc( size).

It is better to implement some error handlers for failed memory allocation and inputs through **[scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)** ( check the return values of malloc and scanf )

Comment: Missing  check of `malloc` failure: `if (arr==NULL) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);};` and useless use of cast for `malloc`; BTW `scanf` can also fail and your code don't check that. So please **edit your answer** to improve it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what should I check in case of scanf?

Comment: Read more about [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). It returns an item count which should be tested... Sometimes `%n` is also helpful.

Comment: So edit again your answer to improve it. Then I will upvote it!

Comment: BTW, argument to malloc is a `size_t` (64 bits on my Linux desktop, same as `unsigned long`) not an `int` (often 32 bits).  So better declare `size_t size;` (and that would matter for huge matrixes of a billion numbers)

Comment: Thanks for having improved your (probably first) answer on SO. I upvoted it and I believe it should be the accepted answer. You should improve it even more by adding relevant links to documentation and a few sentences of explanations. BTW, I believe you should remove the empty lines in your code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you so much, your comments were so informative. Glad to solve problems with the help of people like you :)

Comment: You really should **edit your answer a bit more to explain in English sentences something about it**. A "code only" answer is poor taste on SO.

Comment: I removed my upvote and will put it again when you'll edit even more. SO is for *human* readers, who need explanation in *English* (not only C code)... Your "Try this" is really not enough.

Comment: Thanks. I think OP should accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your program [here](https://ideone.com/rp1bDi). No error. Perhaps that was coincidence and just happened to run but maybe you got error when you printed the values inside the loop like [this](https://ideone.com/BaSJ4W)?

If so, that's because during the last iteration you try to write a part of memory that wasn't allocated to using `malloc()`. Like `arr[6]` when only till `arr[5]` was actually allocated when n=2 and m=3. Doing so invokes undefined behavior. Look at the links [@Basil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) pointed out in the comments.

You must check the value returned by `malloc()` to find if the memory allocation was successful. If it failed, a `NULL` would be returned.

And the `scanf()`'s return value may be checked to find if it was successful or not. It returns the number of successful assignments which in the case of the `scanf()` in the loop must be `1`. If it isn't `1` some error has occurred.

This is another way of writing that loop

```
for( i=0;i<m*n && scanf("%d", arr+i)==1;i++);
```